# serial communication using c++ .in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, serial-port

i can send 1 byte char type data serially. now i am stuck with sending float type data . here is my code for sending data serially .

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyO1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
char byte_out[] = {0x47};
write(fd, byte_out, strlen(byte_out)+1);
```

how can i write(or send) float type data serially . Please help me . thanks in advance .

Comment: You should define the protocol and the binary (or textual) representation that you are sending (it may depend on the other side). If possible, choose a textual representation (perhaps [JSON](http://json.org/) could inspire you). And your code is wrong: `byte_out` should be 0 terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing different.. and you need to put the right size of the float type ..

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyO1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
float float_out[] = {1.2342};
write(fd, (void *) float_out, sizeof(float));
```